# Unable to copy SSH rsa key from master to slave in oracle VM

Tags: ssh, connection-timeout, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to setup a multinode cluster in ubuntu. I install ubuntu on oracle VM one is master and one slave. For communication I generate a SSH key on master and trying to copy the same to slave. I am using below command:

```
ssh-copy-id -i /home/kumar/.ssh/id_rsa.pub kumar@slave
```

and I am getting below error:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: Error: ssh: connect to host slave port 22:Connection time out
```

I have added the ip and name of machines in /etc/hosts file.

I am not sure what else I am missing, if you have any workaround please let me know

And if I ping slave form master:

```
ping 10.193.67.255
```

I am getting this:

```
64 bytes from 10.193.67.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time 3.23 ms
64 bytes from 10.193.67.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=254 time 2.69 ms
64 bytes from 10.193.67.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=254 time 3.23 ms
64 bytes from 10.193.67.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=254 time 2.91 ms
```

Comment: The error message says that a connection to `slave` could not be established. Maybe the `sshd` on the remote system `slave` is not running or access is blocked by firewall (i.e. `iptables`) rules.

Comment: Yes, but  i have already disbale the iptables and sshd is running on slave.

Comment: What does a `ssh kumar@slave` say? Same error message? `iptables` both on master and slave disabled? Any other firewall in between?

Comment: Yes same message and no there are no other firewalls.

Comment: OK, one step back: `ping slave`?

Comment: edited answer with the result

Comment: Then you should check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406245/limit-ssh-access-to-specific-clients-by-ip-address and https://askubuntu.com/questions/262937/restrict-ssh-access-to-specific-ip-for-user and also `DenyUsers`